# Can not log in to a new install BES 5.0.1 on Server 2008 with SQL 2005

Tags: windows-server-2008, login, windows-sbs, bes

Full install of Blackberry Enterprise Server 5.0.1

Install completes OK but can not login to BES admin server Login or Password error
all of the checks are OK on install server is a member server on a sbs2008 domain
BESAdmin is an administrator and has has local admin rights.

if any one has any thoughts I would be most greatful

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the software and use blackberry authentication rather than Active Directory authentication.